# GCP VPC | Invalid value for field 'region': 'asia-northeast3'. Unknown region

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I create new VPC with subnet, it can't deploy vpc with error: 
 `gcloud sdk : Invalid value for field 'region': 'asia-northeast3'. Unknown region.`

gcp console : `Permission denied on 'locations/asia-northeast3' (or it may not exist).`

is there any problem? when I create in asia-northeast2, it working fine! asia-northeast3 isn't working.

Comment: [asia-northeast3-a/b/c](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) is different from asia-northeast2 having [sole-tenant nodes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes).

Comment: Have you tried to switch to the local currency (KRW) while using asia-northeast3 region? I found this possible solution at [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153365191).

Comment: What makes the VPC subnet different from northeast3 and northeast2?

All currencies are set in Korean. I still get an error when creating the cabinet.

Comment: Please update your question with your commands. What do you mean by "still get an error when creating the cabinet"?